How to play svg animation on a website? TypeError: svgObject.beginElement is not a function
I'm beginner in the programming!Please help me!!!I have the svg animation file and i want when i click the button on my website the svg will play.
But it give me the issue:TypeError: svgObject.beginElement is not a function.
here is my code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>svg</title>
</head>
<body>
  <object type="image/svg+xml" id="svganimate" begin="indefinite" data="sample.svg"></object>
  <button onclick="playAnimation()">Play Animation</button>
  
  <script>
    function playAnimation() {
      var svgObject = document.getElementById('svganimate');
      svgObject.beginElement();
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>

Can someone help me please!

beginElement can only be called on animation elements: <animate>, <animateMotion> <object> is not an animation element. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/begin

The error TypeError: svgObject.beginElement is not a function occurs because the object tag in HTML does not have a beginElement method and also ensure that your SVG file (sample.svg) contains the animate element and that the selector accurately targets it. here is a revised answer to clear the error in your console.


 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <title>SVG Animation</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <object type="image/svg+xml" id="svganimate" data="sample.svg"></object>
      <button onclick="playAnimation()">Play Animation</button>
      
      <script>
        function playAnimation() {
          var svgObject = document.getElementById('svganimate');
          var svgDoc = svgObject.contentDocument; 
    
          if (svgDoc) {
            var animateElement = svgDoc.querySelector('animate'); 
            if (animateElement) {
              animateElement.beginElement(); 
            } 
          }
        }
      </script>
    </body>
    </html>




Hello!Thank you for anwser,so there is no issue right now,but animation still doesn't play,can you help please

And i don't now,why but,svgDoc is null,do you know why?

@Николай Киселёв: You can't instantly access the content of an <object> element. You need to wait for the content to be fully loaded e.g by using a load event listener. See also "External svg plugged in by  has no reaction on change height in svg"

ok,i'll try,thank u
